How to calculate the latitude/longitude by the RPM in the basin?
By seeing how the water swirls and whirlpools when going down the drain in a washbasin is it possible to tell something about the longitude or latitude where the individual is?

No. It is not possible.  Coriolis force, if measured precisely, might give the latitude ---  but is far to small to affect water going down a washbasin drain. You need a huge tank and weeks of waiting to see any effect. Longitude cannot  be measured without a clock to give you Greenwich Mean Time.

I'd love to see a calculation of the latitude.

Use a Foucault pendulum to determine the lattitude. For water see: https://www.nature.com/articles/2071084a0 and https://www.nature.com/articles/1961080b0.pdf
